# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'State'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, ef-database-first, using-statement

I encounter this error in my project:

> **Error    CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'State' and no extension method 'State' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

This error cause to fail of **Update** and **Delete** queries.because of this lines:

```
db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

I guess, the specific library or reference is cleaned.
Can you guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try db.SaveChanges() for update entity and .Remove(entity) for delete entity.